# How to determine whether a set spans $P^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi all I'm having trouble with this homework question:

"Is the following a spanning set for the vector space $P^2$ of polynomial functions of degree at most $2$?

$1/2$, $t^2 + t$, $t^2 − 1$."

So I know if it is a spanning set then all polynomial functions of degree at most 2 can be written as a linear combination of the functions given. What I was thinking is setting up an equation like this:

$a*1/2$$+b(t^2+t)$$+c(t^2-1)$$=dt^2+et+f$

Where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are in $R$

This seems like a lot of work though so is there a quicker and easier way?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. In order for it to be a spanning set it should be possible to build all of them with linear combinations of the polynomials from the set.

Comment: Set the right hand side equal to 0 then show that a, b and c must all be 0 (equate coefficients to create 3 simultaneous equations). See your notes on the definition of linear independence to see that this suffices to answer the question.

Comment: Why do I need to show linear independace. I thought that was only needed when you wanted the minimal spanning set.

Comment: You can demonstrate that each of standard basis $1$, $t$, $t^2$ may be formed by linear combination of the given polynomials. For example, $2*(1/2) = 1$, so $1$ is in the span, $(t^2-1)+1 = t^2$ so $t^2$ is in the span, etc.

Comment: How would you do this if you were asked a similar question about a set of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$?